# Undefined variable inside Laravel view when using Mail

Tags: laravel-5

While trying to send verification email using Laravel 5.2, I get an error:

> Undefined variable: confirmation_code (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\email\verify.blade.php)

My code looks like this:

*Controller.php:*

```
     public function postSignup(Request $request){                                                                               
       $this->validate($request,[
       'email'=>'required|unique:users|email',
       'name'=>'required|max:50|min:3',
       'password'=>'required|min:6',
       'con-password'=>'required|same:password',
               ]);

    $confirmation_code=['code'=>str_random(20)];
    $name = $request->input('name');

    Mail::send('email.verify',$confirmation_code,function($message)
        use($request,$name){
        $message->to($request->input('email'),$name)
                ->subject('Verify Your Email Address');
    });


    User::create([
            'email'=>$request->input('email'),
            'name'=>$request->input('name'),                
            'password'=>bcrypt($request->input('password'))                          
        ]);

    return redirect()->back()->with('info','Congratulation you have been successfully registered.Please check your email for verification');
    }
```

*Mail.verify.blade.php:*

```
    <h2>Verify Your Email Address</h2>

    <div>
        Thanks for creating an account with the verification demo app.
        Please follow the link below to verify your email address
        {{ URL::to('register/verify/'.$confirmation_code) }}.<br/>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mail::send('email.verify', compact('confirmation_code'), function ($message) use($request, $name) {
    $message->to($request->input('email'),$name)
            ->subject('Verify Your Email Address');
});
```

The reason why it fails is that Laravel views accept an associative array as their data, so that it can turn them into variables using keys as variables names and match them to their corresponding values.

What `compact` does is turn your variable into an associative array, with the name of the variable as its key (sort of the opposite of what the Laravel view will do).